# Input not being assigned in a switch situation

Tags: javascript

So I know ive cluttered this to High heaven and back but it should work. My only problem is that im not getting a returned value for my input of homeValue. Therefore none of my taxes can be applied. Here is the original problem statement:

Ps. Sorry for just straight asking this the other day, I had left my Flashdrive at home and have this due later this week so I wanted to get it posted today.

You have been asked to write a property tax program for the tri-county area.  If you live in Charleston county then you owe 1 percent of your home's value if it's less than or equal to $50,000.  You owe 1.50 percent if it's greater than $50,000 but not greater than $150,000 and 2 percent if it's greater than $150,00.  If you live in Dorchester county then you owe 1.25 percent of your home's value if it's less than or equal to $50,000.  You owe 1.50 percent if it's greater than $50,000 but not greater than $150,000 and 1.75 percent if it's greater than $150,000.  If you live in Berkeley county then you owe 2 percent of your home's value if it's less than or equal to $50,000 of value, 2.25 percent if it's greater than $50,000 but not greater than $150,000 and 2.75 percent if it's greater than $150,000.

At the end of the program they want to see the value for the home, the county it resides in and the property tax owed.  You must use Switch logic when selecting the county in your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

//assumptions
var lowValue = 50000;
var medValue = 150000;
var highValue, taxCode, valueCode;
var charleston1 = .01;
var charleston2 = .015;
var charleston3 = .02;
var dorchester1 = .0125;
var dorchester2 = .015;
var dorchester3 = .0175;
var berkeley1 = .02;
var berkeley2 = .0225;
var berkeley3 = .0275;
var county, taxOwed, tax;
var charleston, dorchester, berkeley;
var homeValue = 0;

//input
homeValue = prompt("How much is the property worth?","");
homeValue = parseInt(homeValue);
county = prompt("Which county do you live in?", "");

//calculations

 switch (county)
 {
    case "charleston":
     taxCode = charleston;
     break;
    case "dorchester":
        taxCode = dorchester;
        break;
    case "berkeley":
        taxCode = berkeley;
        break;
    default:
                    alert("You didnt enter a proper county.");
                    break;  
 }    
switch (homeValue)
{
 case (homeValue):
            valueCode = lowValue;
            break;
 case (homeValue <= medValue):
            valueCode = medValue;
            break;
 case (homeValue > medValue):
            valueCode = highValue
 default:

                 break;
}           

switch (taxCode)
{
             case (charleston && lowValue):
             homeTax = charleston1;
             break;
             case (charleston && medValue):
             homeTax = charleston2;
             break;
             case (charleston && highValue):
             homeTax = charleston3;
             break

             case (dorchester && lowValue):
             homeTax = dorchester1;
             break;
             case (dorchester && medValue):
             homeTax = dorchester2
             break
             case (dorchester && highValue):
             homeTax = dorchester3
             break;

             case (berkeley && lowValue):
             homeTax = berkeley1;
             break;
             case (berkeley && medValue):
             homeTax = berkeley2;
             break;
             case (berkeley && highValue):
             homeTax = berkeley3;
             break;
             Default:
             alert("somethings wrong");
}    
totalTax = homeValue * homeTax;


//output
document.write("$" + homeValue + " house in " + county + " County.");
document.write("Tax owed: $" + totalTax);

// -->
</script>
```

Comment: The variables that you assign to `taxCode` in the first switch don’t have any values assigned to them, so “comparing” them afterwards does not make sense. And the second switch is just wrong, you can only use conditions in cases if you use `switch(true)` (also you rather _shouldn’t_). And those conditions don’t make much sense either. I think you’ll have to go learn some JavaScript basics first …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var county, homeValue, taxOwed;

//input
homeValue = prompt("How much is the property worth?","");
homeValue = parseInt(homeValue);
county = prompt("Which county do you live in?", "");

switch (county)
{
    case "charleston":
    if (homeValue <= 50000) {
        taxOwed = homeValue * 0.01;    
    }
    else if (homeValue > 50000 && homeValue < 150000) {
        taxOwed = homeValue * 0.015;
    }
    else {
        taxOwed = homeValue * 0.02;
    }
    break;

    case "dorchester":
    if (homeValue <= 50000) {
        taxOwed = homeValue * .0125;    
    }
    else if (homeValue > 50000 && homeValue < 150000) {
        taxOwed = homeValue * 0.015;
    }
    else {
        taxOwed = homeValue * 0.0175;
    }
    break;

    case "berkeley":
    if (homeValue <= 50000) {
        taxOwed = homeValue * 0.02;    
    }
    else if (homeValue > 50000 && homeValue < 150000) {
        taxOwed = homeValue * 0.0225;
    }
    else {
        taxOwed = homeValue * 0.0275;
    }
    break;

    default:
        alert("You didnt enter a proper county.");
        break;  
}    



//output
alert("Your house in " + county + " has a value of $" + homeValue + " and tax owed is $" + taxOwed);
```